# How to declare a variable in Typescript that has all fields of existing interface plus others

Tags: typescript, extend

For example  I have interface

```
export Interface IPerson { name: string, age: number }

person: IPerson = { name: 'Mary', age: 20 };
```

and I want to declare something like:

superPerson that has all fields from IPerson plus field ***score***

```
superPerson: { score: number } extends IPerson = { name: 'Mary', age: 20, score: 170}
```

without defining a new Interface or Type separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be done with an intersection type:

```
superPerson: IPerson & { score: number } = { name: 'Mary', age: 20, score: 170 }
```

Note that if you did this on a separate line it would be nearly identical, just you'd have a name for the type, which can make it easier for puny humans to understand, and allows reuse of the type.

```
type SuperPerson = IPerson & { score: number };
superPerson: SuperPerson = { name: 'Mary', age: 20, score: 170};
```